# Can Python's set absence of ordering be considered random order?

Tags: python, random, set, shuffle

I'd like to know if the absence of element ordering of the Python's built-in `set` structure is "random enough". For instance, taking the iterator of a set, can it be considered a shuffled view of its elements?

(If it matters, I'm running Python 2.6.5 on a Windows host.)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No, it is *not* random. It is "arbitrarily ordered", which means that you cannot depend on it being either ordered or random.

Comment: It's important to understand the difference between "undefined" and "random".

Comment: Indeed, the order is predictable from the ID's of the various objects in the set.  It's quite rigorously defined by the code.  BUT -- bonus -- the details are none of your business, making them "arbitrary" and "implementation-specific" and "undependable for anything".  And "undefined as far as you're allowed to care."

Comment: OK. The hash function will determine the order. For instance, for integer elements we'll get the natural order. So, I conclude that we'll have an "undefined", "arbitrary" and "repeatable" ordering for the same set of elements.

Comment: It might only be repeatable under a single implementation of Python. If the spec says it's undefined, don't assume anything else about it (not even repeatability).

Comment: Undefined means "changeable without notice".  So an upgrade from 2.6.1 to 2.6.2 i allowed to change things that are otherwise undefined.

Comment: The comments of this answer are as good as the answer it self. Too bad you can't share rep.

Answer (score 6):

In a word, no:

```
>>> list(set(range(10000))) == list(range(10000))
True
```

Comment: Agreed, just did similar tests myself and got these results.

Answer (score 6):

Just a note about the rigorously of the order. It seems that it is very unreliable even in the same running environment.

For example this code gives different answers:

```
data = 'KSRNDOW3GQ'
chars = set(data)
print(list(chars))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

No, you can not rely on it for any real statistical purpose. The implementation of sets in Python is in terms of a hash table, and can cause the element distribution to display some very non-random properties. There's a large gap between "not having a guaranteed order" and "guaranteed to be unordered in a uniform-random manner".

Use `random.shuffle` to *really* shuffle elements of a sequence.

Comment: The thing is `random.shuffle` may only be used for sequences, which a `set` is not. One may convert it to a `list` but for a big number of elements and performance sensitive code it may be an issue...

Answer (score 4):

Arbitrariness is central when designing programs, each of these freedoms that you reserve **is like a joker card** that you can use when you implement, develop, or rewrite your program. The more of these free-cards you collect, the more efficiency can you deliver from your code (probably), since you have more freedom to change it.

It is not random, it's only freedom. If it's a better set that way, the order can be forwards on Wednesdays and "backwards" on Fridays.