# SyntaxError: can't assign to function call in Python (Beginner)

Tags: python

I am running the following block of code:

```
def update_contact_number(contacts, contact_name, old_number, new_number):
    if contact_name in contacts:    
        lis = list(contacts[contact_name].values())
        lis[0]=new_number
        contacts[contact_name].values()=tuple(lis)
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

when I get this error:

> SyntaxError: can't assign to function call.

Can anyone come up with a solution and the possible problem?

Comment: The problem is that you haven't actually figured out what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please describe what `contacts[contact_name]` can be, and how exactly you want to update it.

Answer (score 4):

The line:

```
contacts[contact_name].values()=tuple(lis)
```

Is not syntactically correct.

As to how to achieve what you want... you did *not* state what you want so nobody can help you.

It seems like you want to change the number of a contact, but then I don't understand why `contacts[contact_name]` would be a `dict`. Also note that if this is true:

```
lis[0]=new_number
```

Here `lis[0]` is basically a *random* value contained in that dictionary, because the order of the keys and values of a dictionary is *undefined*.

Comment: Not random, but [arbitrary](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2860339/).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Well, since in last versions of python there's hash randomization it is indeed random. It is arbitrary only during a *single* execution of the program but running the program multiple times can give different results.

Comment: What help I was seeking for is looking for tips on why the code was not working. The error language is too cryptic to make out. The dictionary and the order was defined as a global variable. I just posted the snippet which was having bugs. You got it right, Thanks!